# cakephp code is not working for alphanumeric validation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

we have tried several solution for validation of password,but none is working but user get login, all validations get working except  alphanumeric validation in password.

Here is code:

```
'password' => array ('required' => array (

    'rule' => array ('notEmpty'),
    'rule' => array ('between',1,15 ),

    //'rule'    => array('custom', '[a-zA-Z0-9, ]+'),
    'message' => 'A password is required,must be between 8 to 15 characters' )
),
```

using custom function it doesn't work so we tried

```
'alphaNumeric' => array(
    'rule'     => array('alphaNumericDashUnderscore'),
    'rule'     => 'alphaNumeric',
    'required' => true,
    'message'  => 'password must contain Alphabets and numbers only'
)),
```

custom function in  model

```
public function alphaNumericDashUnderscore($check) {
    $value = array_values($check);
    $value = $value[0];

    return preg_match('|^[0-9a-zA-Z_-]*$|', $value);
}
```

we are working on cakephp version 2.4.3

Answer (score 4):

That is because you are defining two times the same key `rule` in an array. The second one will always overwrite the first one.

As per [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#multiple-rules-per-field), you should do it as follow:

```
public $validate = array(
    'password' => array(
        'password-1' => array(
            'rule'    => 'alphaNumeric',
            'message' => 'password must contain Alphabets and numbers only',
         ),
        'password-2' => array(
            'rule'    => 'alphaNumericDashUnderscore',
            'message' => 'password must contain Alphabets and numbers only'
        )
    )
);
```